# How to add second permalink to page?

Tags: wordpress, redirect, permalinks

I have a page with a URL like
`http://www.example.com/subcategory/therealthing`.

This URL should stay like this but I need to create a shortcut that looks like
`http://www.example.com/realthing`

That shortcut should take the user to the site with the longer URL

**A method that is SEO friendly would be perfect.**

What's the easiest way if I don't want to change the permalink of the original site? I guess htaccess won't work for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Funny, I just answered something very similar to this. See the redirection plugin. Much easier than editing your .htaccess file yourself. Particularly if you need to do it a lot.

Take a look at the feature list for the [redirection plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/). This allows you to setup redirects to other pages or do [pass through](http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/redirection/) redirections.

Comment: If I were to do this for a post rather than a category, is there a plugin/way to set up this redirection in the post itself? I am looking to redirect domain.com/xyz to domain.com/posttype/long-post-title/

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy with redirects .. then you can add this kind of rule into your htaccess file (but it has to be placed **before** WordPress rules -- if not sure/does not work -- provide your current whole .htaccess):

```
RewriteRule ^realthing$ /subcategory/therealthing [R=301,L]
```

or you can try

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/realthing$ /subcategory/therealthing
```

Answer (score -1):

Redirection is not a more reliable solution. You should use this plugin in which you can customize every permalink without any problem https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/